# Pass a value into $mdDialog controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a value from controller to the service using $mdDialog. The var id has the value but when I go to the testService the value is not there.

```
module.controller('viewTestController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $mdDialog, testService) {
var self = this;
self.$onInit = function () {
    self.test = function () {
        var id = $scope.$parent.key;
        console.log(id);

        $mdDialog.show(
             locals: { dataToPass: id },
             templateUrl: '/test.html',
             title: "Test",
             clickOutsideToClose: true,
             scope: $scope,
             preserveScope: true,
             controller: function ($scope) {

                 $scope.finalizeTest = function (dataToPass) {
                     testService.finalizeTest(dataToPass);
                     $mdDialog.cancel();
                 };
             }
         });
    };
} 
});
```

Comment: You have made a typo mistake. Just correct=>  locals: { dataToPass: id }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass your `locals` attribute directly into your controller function like:

```
$mdDialog.show(
    locals: { dataToPass: id },
    templateUrl: '/test.html',
    title: "Test",
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    scope: $scope,
    preserveScope: true,
    controller: function ($scope, $mdDialog, dataToPass) {
        $scope.finalizeTest = function () {
            testService.finalizeTest(dataToPass);
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a typo when I entered the code in stockoverflow. In my code I don't have the typo.